# Setting all items in an array to a number without for loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, shortcut

Right now, to set all items in an array to, say, 0, I have to loop through the entire thing to preset them.

Is there a function or shortcut which can defaultly set all values to a specific number, when the array is stated? Like so:

```
int array[100] = {0*100}; // sets to {0, 0, 0... 0}
```

Comment: If you are flexible in using std::vector, then you can initialize during construction like `std::vector<int> v (100 /* length */, 42 /* initial value */);`

Comment: `{0*100}` looks a bit strange. On one hand, 0 * 100 == 0 and correct ([answer of Denise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270595/7478597)). On the other hand, it looks like a repetition of 0 is intended to express. That doesn't work that way. And, btw. 0 is the only possible value for an array initializer in that manner.

Comment: It's just an example.

Comment: _It's just an example._ Yeah, but a somehow confusing... ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that. I just wasn't sure if that would work because it works with Python.

Comment: Oh oh. Please, don't try to apply Python knowledge to C++ too much. That may lead you into a wrong direction. C++ and Python are both imperative languages, and certain things might look similar but they are still very different languages where C++ especially has a lot of subtleties you have to care about (but would never consider such stuff in Python). First of all, memory management...

Comment: Okay. Dart and C++ are pretty similar though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239937/discussion-between-skyrider-feyrs-and-scheffs-cat).

Comment: @SkyriderFeyrs In python it is `[0]*3 -> [0, 0, 0]` not `[0*100] -> [0]`. Unrelated: Be careful while using multiplication on lists in python you'd be victim of [changes in sublist are relected across the list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/12416453)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I have to review my homework... 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set all the values to `0` then you can use:

```
int array[100] = {0}; //initialize array with all values set to 0
```

If you want to set some value other than `0` then you can use `std::fill` from **algorithm** as shown below:

```
int array[100];  //not intialized here
std::fill(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 45);//all values set to 45
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int array[100] = {0};
```

should do the job
Please refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization)

```
int a[3] = {0}; // valid C and C++ way to zero-out a block-scope array
int a[3] = {}; // invalid C but valid C++ way to zero-out a block-scope array
```

Comment: This one only sets it to 0 though...

Comment: Yep , sorry according to your example, I thought the specific number should be 0.
int arr[100] = {1}; leads to an array with a 1 in the first position and 0 for the rest of the 99 positions.

Answer (score 2):

Going forward you should use std::array instead of C-style arrays. So this become:

```cpp
std::array<int,100> array;
array.fill(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use vectors, which are more flexible than array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
std::vector<int>v(100,10); // set 100 elements to 10
}
```

Try running this:
https://onlinegdb.com/2qy1sHcQU

Comment: I am pretty sure this initializes only the first element. https://godbolt.org/z/36e3EYKE1

Comment: Yes, only the first element.

Comment: @Jellyboy you are right let me edit

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize the array using a function's return value:

```
#include <algorithm>

int generateSomeValue( )
{
    int result { };
    // some operations here to calculate result

    return result;
}

int main( )
{
    int array[ 100 ];
    std::generate( std::begin( array ), std::end( array ), generateSomeValue );
}
```